# Invalid Outside Procedures and Syntax in VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to programming/coding, and I'm having problems with my code.

I'm currently trying to write a macro in excel that will go through an excel document and insert a partially blank row on duplicate columns.

I'm currently using Excel 2010

So for example if the excel sheet contained:

```
Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E
       1     Apples        1        40      Blue
       1    Bananas        2        50       Red
       1    Oranges        3        60      Pink
       2   Cherries         
       3      Kiwis
```

Then the script would sort it into:

```
Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E
       1     Apples        1        40      Blue
       1    Bananas        
       1    Oranges        
       2   Cherries        2        50       Red
       3      Kiwis        3        60      Pink
```

Thus sorting the data by Column A and C while also creating blank spaces in C, D, and E if the value in Column A does not equal the value found in Column C.

My code so far:

```
Sub Main()
Dim a As Long, c As Long
Dim objRange As Range
Dim strCIDCol1 As String, strCIDCol3 As String

a = 1 'row counter for Column A
c = 1 'row counter for Column C

Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1) = ""
    'sets the loop to run until A1 is blank
    strCIDCol1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1)
        'sets the value of A1 as CIDCol1
    strCIDCol3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, 3)
        'sets the value of C1 as CIDCol3
    If (strCIDCol1 <> strCIDCol2) Then 
        'runs until A(a) and C(c) are not equal
        Set objRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, 3).Range(Cells(c, 3), Cells(c, 5))
        objRange.Activate
            'Selects Columns C, D, and E
        objRange.Insert (xlShiftDown)
            'Inserts "Shift Row Down"
        strCIDCol1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(a + 1, 1)
            'moves on
    End If
    a = a + 1 'adds 1 to counter to move to next row
    c = c + 1 'adds 1 to counter to move to next row
Loop
End Sub
```

I keep getting "invalid outside procedure" errors on

```
a = 1
c = 1
```

and

```
a = a + 1
c = c + 1
```

I'm also getting a 1004 error "insert method of range class failed" on

```
objRange.Insert (xlShiftDown)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing with objRange. I saw the code online and tried to adapt it to fit what I needed. The way it was explained was that objRange was used to highlight the selected areas Column C, D, and E in this case. And then Insert would shift the cells down by inserting a row above the highlighted cells.

Comment: // is not used in VBA to comment. Replace // with '

Comment: @Tony what is `objExcel`. It seems this is part of your code and I bet that the error is triggered by something that you don't show us now.

Comment: Handy tip: don't use Integer for row counts because they can only hold signed 16 bit values (max 32767). Use Long instead.

Comment: "Invalid outside procedure" means you have an executable statement that's outside of a procedure scope. Since this is a compile-time error, the editor should be highlighting the faulting tokens. Where is the error happening? Do you have an `End Sub` somewhere inside that procedure, in code that you stripped out?

Comment: @Masoud I found the original code online and tried to adapt it to fit what I need. The original code was from a tech blog "Scripting Dad" or something.

Comment: Please stop adding meta-comments about why you're editing stuff. There's a field specifically meant for that, that people interested in the [revisions history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44396902/revisions) can see; your post doesn't need them, readers don't care how many times you've edited it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh my bad, I didn't see the edit summary part before, I was just editing and saving before. I'll use it from now on, thanks!

Comment: Const xlShiftDown = -4121 is not nesessary, it's already defined in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If (strCIDCol1 <> strCIDCol2) Then
```

You have never defined strCIDCoL2. I think you meant str CIDCol3 here.

```
Set objRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, 3).Range(Cells(c, 3), Cells(c, 5))
```

This is wrong syntax for setting range. Try using:

```
Set objRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(c,3).Range(Cells(c,3), Cells(c,5)))
```

Also are you sure about using objRange.activate instead of objRange.select ?